# Adding a statement in an existing SyntaxList<StatementSyntax>

Tags: c#, vb.net, roslyn

I'm having problems adding a statement in an existing `SyntaxList<StatementSyntax>`.

Basicaly I just want to add a statement when I visit a `MultiLineIfBlock` here is my current implementation of my `VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter` :

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitMultiLineIfBlock(MultiLineIfBlockSyntax node)
{
        var result = (MultiLineIfBlockSyntax)base.VisitMultiLineIfBlock(node);
        var statements = result.Statements.Insert(0, this._newStatement);
        return result.WithStatements(statements);
}
```

Output:

```
 BEFORE
            If (True) Then
                Console.Write("FirstLine")
                Console.Write("SecondLine")
                Console.Write("ThirdLine")
            End If

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AFTER
            If (True) Then
Console.Write("AddedStatement")                Console.Write("FirstLine")
                Console.Write("SecondLine")
                Console.Write("ThirdLine")
            End If
```

Like you can see the result is not a valid tree...
Any help will be appreciate!

**UPDATE**

I added an EndOfLine TrailingTrivia and here is the output:

```
            If (True) Then
Console.Write("AddedStatement")
                Console.Write("FirstLine")
                Console.Write("SecondLine")
                Console.Write("ThirdLine")
            End If
```

What is going on with the indentation ? I have to do something wrong...

Comment: You probably just need to run the formatter.

Comment: Normalizewhitespace?

Comment: You'll probably want to add at least a new line after the statement.  But you will definitely not see correct formatting until you call the formatter.  If you are doing this as part of a code fix, the formatter will run automatically after your code fix makes changes.

Comment: I runned the Formatter but my statement dont have the right indentation... toughts?